# I want to check whether the user has entered something

Tags: c

I am facing a problem that is is follows:
 a] How to check whether the user has entered something against the scanf statement.
 b] How to run a part of code repeatedly without goto function or what is the replacement for goto.

Comment: have you heard of `loops`?

Comment: a) Check scanf return value (see https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf ), b) use loops

Comment: Please focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while working on this. Maybe show your code. Also, use the comments above to contrast your problem to the seemingly most obvious ways to solve it. If you have not yet heard neither of loops nor of return values, then please first work through a beginners tutorial until you know to use them. Then ask a question on how exactly to use them for solving your problem. By then you should also be able to provide a [mre] demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> a] How to check whether the user has entered something against the scanf statement.

scanf() returns the number of successful inputs scanned and assigned.

> b] How to run a part of code repeatedly without goto function or what is the replacement for goto.

Loops.